# Subprocess создает дочерний процесс, но не запускает скрипт

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, subprocess

Есть сокет-сервер, исправно работающий, попросили сделать к нему минимальные интерфейс, сделал с помощью PyQt5 в нем есть 2 кнопки: Запуск сервера и Выключения сервера, реализованы через subprocess следующим образом:

Запуск:

```
def start_serv(self):
    self.process = subprocess.Popen('python server.py', shell=True)
    logging.info('#' * 80)
    logging.debug(f'Process PID: {self.process.pid}')
    logging.debug(f'Child process return code: {self.process.returncode}')
    self.mb('The server is running!') # отправка сообщения в диалоговое окно
```

Выключение:

```
def stop_serv(self):
    try:
        proc = self.process
        proc.send_signal(signal.SIGTERM)
        while True:
            ex_code = proc.poll()
            if ex_code == None or ex_code == '1':
                proc.wait()
                continue
            else:
                break
        logging.debug(f'Child process exit code: {proc.poll()}')
        logging.debug('The server is stopped!')
        logging.info('#' * 80)
        self.mb('The server is stopped!') # отправка сообщения в диалоговое окно
    except Exception as e:
        logging.warning(f'Error button: {e}')
        self.mb('The server is not running yet!') # отправка сообщения в диалоговое окно
```

В IDE(PyCharm) все работает отлично. Но после сборки с помощью auto-py-to-exe при нажатии на кнопку запуска создается процесс с новым PID, но сервер не стартует. Пути к файлам во время сборки не изменялись.

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться, где и какие правки мне нужно внести, что бы заработало.

P.S.: Все делается на Python 3.8.2 под RED OS (привет импортозамещение).

Comment: У вас server.py включен в exe файл? Если да, то вы его не сможете запустить командой `python server.py`

Comment: @insolor сборка идет в папку, не в один файл.

Comment: Тогда пробуйте заменить сервер на простейший скрипт с while True: print(1); time.sleep(0.5), добавьте логирование того что выводит субпроцесс. Потом уже от этого нужно будет отталкиваться.

Comment: @insolor если заменить на цикл, то скрипт нормально запускается, в логах отписывает свой вывод, далее процесс закрывается по нажатию кнопки.

Comment: Значит какая-то проблема с сервером, нужно сам сервер дебажить.

Comment: @insolor дебаг ничего не показал(((

Comment: он в подпроцесс то не войдет...

Comment: @eri сам сервер дебажил

Comment: @Pavel_G под дебагом я имею в виду отладку в широком смысле, например добавление отладочных принтов / логов. Если просто цикл получается запустить, значит нужно найти место в вашем коде, где что-то перестает работать как надо.

Comment: попробуйте с QProcess https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A217323+qprocess

Comment: @insolor дебаг не просто так ничего не показывал, я косячил не в коде, а на этапе сборки. Теперь все работает, НО только на моей машине))) Спасибо за советы.

Comment: @eri спасибо за советы, было познавательно

Answer (score 0):

'python server.py' - рекомендую использовать полный путь к питону и к запускаемому файлу.

```
python_path = sys.executable

server_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)),"server.py")
```

также может не попасть рабочая папка проекта в cwd при запуске

```
cwd=os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
... Popen(...., cwd=cwd)
```

Comment: спасибо за совет, но результатов не дало. Пробовал еще так делать: `cwd = Path(Path.cwd(), 'server.py')`

Comment: cwd это не путь к файлу, а путь откуда этот файл должен работать.

Comment: я понимаю, может не совсем правильно ответил, через Path я доставал полный путь включая файл, потом вставлял его в вызов процесса:  `self.process = subprocess.Popen(f'python {cwd}', shell=True)`

Comment: cwd это не путь к файлу, в нем другой смысл